# How do you equip mods in warframe?

Tags: warframe

Doesn't tell you how to use them or equip them or anything (without auto equip) Xbox1

Comment: @TimmyJim Look at the end of his original question.

Comment: @Frank ah I see. Didn't realize this was the same op.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your arsenal (esc -> equipment -> arsenal) whilst in your ship and select "Upgrade" on the Warframe or piece of equipment you wish to install mods to. Drag mods from the bottom area to a slot install them.